# LUKS encrypted disk with pop_os installed booting into initramfs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, luks, initramfs, pop-os

I've purchased a new SSD and created partitions for root, home, swap and boot.
I've encrypted root, home and swap using LUKS following the directions at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/order-management-sw/10.0?topic=considerations-encrypting-data-partitions-using-luks.

Upon going through all the steps, I've installed pop_os on the partitioned SSD using the partitions I created earlier for /, /home, swap and /boot respectively.

I go to reboot and now the machine boots up with the gray pop_os background but no.login prompt. Hitting enter a few times drops me into an 'initramfs' shell.
I suspect the OS isn't booting because it is encrypted. I've scoured the internet looking for a solution but to no avail.

If what is happening makes sense to you, can you please assist because it is not obvious what I should be doing to boot up my LUKS encrypted OS install.

Comment: If you want to encrypt root partition of Linux, you need to re-config initramfs image to find out correct root partition, I don't see this part in the page you pasted. 

basically, Linux needs to open encrypted disk and mount it, then boot.

you can refer to this page for more details: https://devconnected.com/how-to-encrypt-root-filesystem-on-linux/#Re-configure_initramfs_image

If you don't configure remote key server to auto open partition, you should see passphrase prompt when booting up if everything goes well.